# finding probability density function

Tags: probability

Let $x$ be random variable with cdf
$ F(x)=0, x\leq 0 $ and $f(x)=1-e^{-x}, x>0$
The value of $P(\frac{1}{4}\leq e^{-x}\leq \frac{1}{3})$ is

(A) $\frac{1}{12}$

(B) $\frac{1}{3}$

(C) $\frac{1}{4}$

(D) $e^{-3}-e^{-4}$.

I know that  $P(a\leq X\leq b)=F(b)-F(a)+P(X=a)$ i am using this but i get none of the above answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will change notation, and use caps for random variables. So the random variable will be called $X$. Then $e^{-X}$ is also a random variable.

We have 
$$\frac{1}{4}\le e^{-X} \le \frac{1}{3}\quad\text{ if and only if}\quad  \ln(1/4) \le -X\le \ln(1/3),$$ that is, if and only if $\,\ln 3\le X\le \ln 4$.

Now we can use the formula you quoted. 
$$\Pr(\ln 3\le X\le \ln 4)=(1-e^{-\ln 4}) -(1-e^{-\ln 3})=e^{-\ln 3}-e^{-\ln 4},$$ 
that is, $\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}$, which simplifies to $\frac{1}{12}$.